# Implementing beep sounds into Android application

Tags: android, audio

I have an application with the desired functionality.

Howerver, at certain times toasts are displayed and I want a double beep to play at the same time that the toasts are displayed to alert the user to the messages being displayed.

I'm not sure what the best approach is for playing sounds in android or if there is some default sounds that I could access to use for the alerts.

**UPDATE**

I have the following code in my main activity file:

```
  public void playAlertTone(final Context context){
            Thread t = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer player = null;
                        int countBeep = 0;
                        while(countBeep<2){
                        player = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.beep);
                        player.start();
                        countBeep+=1;
                        try {

                                        
                            Thread.sleep(player.getDuration()+100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        }
                    }
                };
                t.start();   

            }
```

I have a sound file named beep in **res/raw**

How can I call this method in an if statement where a toast is displayed so the 2 occur at the same time?

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the code where I'm trying to call the alerting method:

```
  if (elapsedTime > hourAlert)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("HOUR PASSED");

            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 160);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
            playAlertTone(getApplicationContext()); // Edited here now call
```

Comment: post the code where you are displaying Toast and calling this Method

Comment: See the code snippet under UPDATE 2

Comment: I have edited this `playAlertTone(getApplicationContext()); // Edited here now call`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your audio file in **res/raw** folder of your Project

and play audio in a thread

```
public  void playAlertTone(final Context context){

      
    Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                MediaPlayer player = null;
                int countBeep = 0;
                while(countBeep<2){
                player = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.beep);
                player.start();
                countBeep+=1;
                try {
                                         
                                // 100 milisecond is duration gap between two beep
                    Thread.sleep(player.getDuration()+100);
                                       player.release();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                           

                }
            }
        };

        t.start();   
        
    }

//call it like this from your activity' any method



    if(myCondition){
    
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration).show();
    
    playAlertTone(getApplicationContext());
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Ok I'm in the process of trying this approach. I've added this method to my main activity but I'm not sure how to call it within an if statement. For example, I have a timer that displays a toast after 10 seconds, how can I call the method above to play the beep at the same time as the toast. Any ideas?

Comment: you can call. pass Context as a parameter to this Method. test your approach and let me know what happens .

Comment: like this playAlertTone(context); ? - It says context cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: `Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);` see this code you are using to show a Toast. pass the same first parameter `context` in `playAlertTone(context)` method .

Comment: My toast is set up in a slightly different way as it is a custom toast. See the code snippet under UPDATE 2 for the code where I'm trying to call the method. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `MediaPlayer`,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

There's a lot to know about how to use, which is covered in the link above. Here's a shirt snippet that illustrates the usage,

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(...);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    mediaPlayer.release();
} catch (IOException e) {
    mediaPlayer.release();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
            }
    });
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("gavel_single.wav");
    mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    afd.close();
    mMediaplayer.prepare();
    mMediaplayer.start();
    mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

put your music file in asset folder